# split a list and increment for loop by 10

Tags: r

How to split a list in r?
I want to split a list in increment manner.
for ex.:

```
x <- 1:50
n <- 5
spt <- split(x,cut(x,quantile(x,(0:n)/n), include.lowest=TRUE,   labels=FALSE))
```

we get

```
$`1`
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

$`2`
[1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$`3`
[1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

$`4`
[1] 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

$`5`
[1] 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

I don't want this output. I want the output like below,

```
$`1`
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 

$`2`
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$`3`
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

$`4`
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2021 22 23 24 25   26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40

$`5`
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

any idea?
And i also want to know that how to increment for loop by 10 in r?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
lapply(seq(10,50, by=10), function(i) x[1:i])
```

Or as @RichardScriven mentioned in the comments, the `seq(10,50, by=10)` can be replaced by `1:5 * 10L`

Comment: Thanks, and if i want value from some variable in this manner than?

Comment: @priyankanimavat  In this case, the `x` is just a sequence.  But if we have other values in `x`, use the `1:i` as index for `x` i.e. `x[1:i]`

Comment: Or `1:5 * 10L` in place of `seq` if we want to be fancy.

Comment: @RichardScriven Thanks, that is a nice option.